# how can I confirm my java run with using the multi thread mechanism

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I make sure my code has used multi thread mechanism ?The first code look like without using mutli thread mechanism. And why the result of second code is unordered？

```
public class ThreadDemo9_2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestThread t = new TestThread() ;
        new Thread(t).start();
        for(int i =0;i < 5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("main thread is running");
        }
    }
}
class TestThread implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("test thread is running");
        }
    }
}
```

The result of ahead code as follows

```
main thread is running
main thread is running
main thread is running
main thread is running
main thread is running
test thread is running
test thread is running
test thread is running
test thread is running
test thread is running
```

well, I changed code as shown below.Just add "i"to distinguish.

```
public class ThreadDemo9_2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestThread t = new TestThread() ;
        new Thread(t).start();
        for(int i =0;i < 5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"main thread is running");
        }
    }
}
class TestThread implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"test thread is running");
        }
    }
}
```

the result is :

```
0main thread is running
0test thread is running
1main thread is running
1test thread is running
2main thread is running
2test thread is running
3main thread is running
4main thread is running
3test thread is running
4test thread is running
```

Comment: Java has multithreading, and the feature works.

Comment: Yes,I am learning to java's multithreading.I just want to konw why the result of my first code seem to be the same as without  multithreading?

Comment: Check [Java 101: Understanding Java threads,](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074217/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-1--introducing-threads-and-runnables.html). Note that your computer can execte about 1mln operation per second. Try to add **Thread.sleep (10);** to method and increase occurence to >20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further synchronisation of your threads to block / wait each other you cannot predict at what time one of your Threads gets time to run and for how long.

If you loop for a few hundred times in your first example you will see the output is "disordered" as well.

Comment: I have looped for 300 times in my first example ,it is still ordered